# Created AWS Athena table but it is not being populated with data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-sagemaker

New to AWS and trying to register Athena with a database table to fill with data from a CSV file that I have uploaded to the S3 bucket.

Here is my code snippet:

```
    # SQL statement to execute
statement = """CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}.{}(
         incident_id string,
         stuff string
         ) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' LOCATION '{}'
""".format(
    database_name, test_table_name_csv, s3_test_csv
)

print(statement)
```

Here is the result of that print statement:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dsoaws.test_table3(
         incident_id string,
         stuff string
         ) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' LOCATION 's3://sagemaker-studio-898900188658-v9o4cft4fj/test-folder/test2.csv'
```

Now when I do a select to try to get the contents of the table:

```
statement = """SELECT * FROM {}.{}
""".format(
    database_name, test_table_name_csv
)

print(statement)

df = pd.read_sql(statement, conn)
```

It just returns an empty table with column names: incident_id and stuff but no rows below that.  I have a test2.csv file which has these two columns and then some a bunch of numbers in incident_id column and then a bunch of random strings in stuff column.  There are about 5 rows.  I made this just as a test file to keep it simple.

There must be something really simple that I am missing?
df.head(5)

Comment: Ans your sample csv file?

Comment: I was able to get it to work just now.  It turns out for the location, the s3 uri you are supposed to just give the path to the folder that the csv file belongs to.  But do you know why it is like this?

Answer (score 1):

When a table is created in Amazon Athena, a `location` is specified. This location is stored with the table definition.

Later, when a query is run against the table, Athena will **look in all files in that directory, including subdirectories** and will use all of those tables to populate the table.

This is convenient because you can **add data to the table** by simply creating an additional file in the directory specified by the location, and even create separate subdirectories for partitioning data.

The location field is specified as `[LOCATION 's3://bucket_name/[folder]/']`, pointing to a directory (not a specific file).

Comment: Now I understand why!  Thanks for the great post.